# Why do I have an extra empty page when I add jquery mobile 1.3.2?

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

When I load the jquery mobile I have an extra empty page that messes with the app (changes to a white page) when I use the options tag in html, for example.

But only when I have `data-native-menu="false"`

This is the extra page:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c" style="min-height: 629px;">
```

Someone can explain to me how to use the jquery mobile without the extra page?

Code:

main:

```
require(['app', 'jquery', 'backbone', './router'], function (App, $, Backbone, Router) {
    'use strict';

    $( document ).on( "mobileinit",
        // Set up the "mobileinit" handler before requiring jQuery Mobile's module
        function() {
            // Prevents all anchor click handling including the addition of active button state and alternate link bluring.
            $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;

            // Disabling this will prevent jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
            $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
            // $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
            $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
                $(event.currentTarget).remove();
            });
        }
    )

    require( ['jquery-mobile-bower'], function() {
        // Instantiates a new Backbone.js Mobile Router
        var router = new Router();
            Backbone.history.start();
    });
});
```

Router:

```
define([ "jquery", "backbone", './views/views'], function($, Backbone, views) {

    var changeView = function(view){
        view.render([{}]);
        $(view.el).attr('data-role', 'page');
        $('body').append(view.el)
        var el = view.el;
        $.mobile.changePage($(view.el));
    }

    // Extends Backbone.Router
    var CategoryRouter = Backbone.Router.extend( {

        // The Router constructor
        initialize: function() {
            // Tells Backbone to start watching for hashchange events
            $('.back').live('click', function(event) {
                window.history.back();
                return false;
            });

        },

        // Backbone.js Routes
        routes: {
            "": "index",
            "aa": "aa"
        },

        // Home method
        index: function(){
            var view = new views.Index();
            changeView(view);
            view.on('changePage', function(pageName){

            })
        },


        aa: function(){
            var view = new views.A();
            changeView(view);
        }

    } );

    // Returns the Router class
    return CategoryRouter;

} );
```

Thanks

Comment: The empty page is a place holer for selectmenu dialog. When you have many options in selectmenu and set `data-native-menu` to false, JQM converts selectmenu into a dialog. If you want native drop down menu, remove that attribute.

Comment: I don't want the native, I want the beautiful one. When I click on the option tag and then I click outside or inside it move me to a white page... that's the problem

Comment: Post code or create a jsfiddle pls.

Comment: i guess the problem is here `$('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
                $(event.currentTarget).remove();
            });` as dialog is a page, and you remove it once `pagehide` is triggered. try delaying `.remove()` by `setTimeout`. __Edit__: Use `.on` instead of `.live` if you're using jQ later than 1.7.

Comment: Well, I've noticed that the 'mobileinit' was never triggered because jquery mobile was already lodaded by another module before so it messes up everything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42284/discussion-between-omar-and-totty)